# Array of States/Cities in a recursive function to output a select with optgroup

Tags: php

I have an array of States/Cities where each element has a `$cities['parent']` key (the value is `0` for States, and `> 0` or Cities, like this:

```
$cities = array(
    '1' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'parent' => '0',
        'name' => 'California',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'parent' => '0',
        'name' => 'Texas',
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'parent' => '0',
        'name' => 'Florida',
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'parent' => '1',
        'name' => 'Los Angeles',
    ),
    '5' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'parent' => '1',
        'name' => 'San Francisco',
    ),
    '6' => array(
        'id' => '6',
        'parent' => '1',
        'name' => 'Sacramento',
    ),
    '7' => array(
        'id' => '7',
        'parent' => '2',
        'name' => 'Houston',
    ),
    '8' => array(
        'id' => '8',
        'parent' => '2',
        'name' => 'Dallas',
    ),
    '9' => array(
        'id' => '9',
        'parent' => '3',
        'name' => 'Miami',
    ),
    '10' => array(
        'id' => '10',
        'parent' => '3',
        'name' => 'Orlando',
    ),
)
```

I also have a recursive function to generate `<select>` options, like this:

```
function citiesSelect($ancestor, $array, $level, $selected = 0) {
    $has_children = false;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['parent'] == $ancestor) {       
            if ($has_children === false && $ancestor) {
                $has_children = true;
            }
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" <?php echo ($value['id']) == $selected ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
            <?php
            citiesSelect($key, $array, $level, $selected);
        }
    }
}
```

And I recall with this:

```
<select>
    <?php citiesSelect(0, $cities, 0); ?>
</select>
```

This is fine (here is a working fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uiax-n03q) but here comes a problem: I'd like to put States in an `<optroup>` so they are not selectable, and resulting in a `<select>` like this:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="California">
        <option value="4">Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="5">San Francisco</option>
        <option value="6">Sacramento</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Texas">
        <option value="7">Houston</option>
        <option value="8">Dallas</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Florida">
        <option value="9">Miami</option>
        <option value="10">Orlando</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

That's fine: how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: thanks to answers that suggest to split into 2 arrays, but sorry I can't modify it! The array yet serves successfully another classic menu (`<ul>...</ul>`) and anyway I could have a third level like:

```
'11' => array(
    'id' => '11',
    'parent' => '4',
    'name' => 'Hollywood',
),
'12' => array(
    'id' => '12',
    'parent' => '4',
    'name' => 'Santa Monica',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I sorted it out with this function (also improved a little bit, to deal with  indentation for nested third/fourth/etc. levels):

```
function citiesSelect($parent, $array, $level, $selected = 0) {
    $has_children = false;
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['parent'] == $parent) {       
            if ($has_children === false && $parent) {
                $has_children = true;
                $level += 1;
            } else if ($parent == 0) {
                echo '<optgroup label="' . $value['name'] . '">' . "\n";    
            }
            if ($parent > 0) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" <?php echo ($value['id']) == $selected ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                <?php echo str_repeat('&rsaquo; ',$level);?><?php echo $value['name']; ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }
            citiesSelect($key, $array, $level);
            if ($parent == 0) { echo '</optgroup>'; };
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the [working fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dack-bcxj)

Thanks to you all for the patience and the time spent

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do everything at once using as few language constructs (arrays and functions). that way you get convoluted code which is difficult to write and will be difficult to read and maintain later.

One way of doing this is :

```
$states = [
    'California' => [
         [
              'id' => 1,
              'name' => 'Los Angeles'
         ],
         [
              'id' => 1,
              'name' => 'San Francisco'
         ]
    ],
    'Florida' => [
         [
              'id' => 1,
              'name' => 'Orlando'
         ],
         ...
    ],
    ....
]
```

That way you can iterate like this :

```
echo "<select>";
foreach ($states as $state) {
    echo "<optgroup label='{$state}>";
    foreach ($state as $city) {
        echo "<option value='{$city['id']}'>{$city['name']}</option>" ;
    }
}
echo "</select>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into two different lists, one for states and another one for cities. Or, even better, make a two-level array: on the first level keep the states and move all the cities from one state into a new list stored as a property of that state. Something like this:

```
$states = array(
    '1' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'California',
        'cities' => array(
            '4' => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'name' => 'Los Angeles',
            ),
            '5' => array(
                'id' => '5',
                'name' => 'San Francisco',
            ),
            '6' => array(
                'id' => '6',
                'name' => 'Sacramento',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Texas',
        'cities' => array(
            '7' => array(
                'id' => '7',
                'name' => 'Houston',
            ),
            '8' => array(
                'id' => '8',
                'name' => 'Dallas',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'Florida',
        'cities' => array(
            '9' => array(
                'id' => '9',
                'name' => 'Miami',
            ),
            '10' => array(
                'id' => '10',
                'name' => 'Orlando',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now, the code becomes much cleaner:

```
function citiesSelect(array $listStates, $selected = 0) {
    foreach($listStates as $stateId => $stateInfo) {
        ?>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo($stateInfo['name']); ?>">
        <?php
        foreach ($stateInfo['cities'] as $cityId => $cityInfo) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cityInfo['id'] ?>" <?php echo ($cityInfo['id']) == $selected ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $cityInfo['name']; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </optgroup>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, i change your style a little bit , but you can fix it.

```
<?php
    function citiesSelect($ancestor, $array, $level, $selected = 0) {
        $has_children = false;

        foreach($array as $stateName => $city)
        {
            foreach($city as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" <?php echo ($value['id']) == $selected ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }

    $cities = array(
        '1' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'parent' => '0',
            'name' => 'California',
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'parent' => '0',
            'name' => 'Texas',
        ),
        '3' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'parent' => '0',
            'name' => 'Florida',
        ),
        '4' => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'parent' => '1',
            'name' => 'Los Angeles',
        ),
        '5' => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'parent' => '1',
            'name' => 'San Francisco',
        ),
        '6' => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'parent' => '1',
            'name' => 'Sacramento',
        ),
        '7' => array(
            'id' => '7',
            'parent' => '2',
            'name' => 'Houston',
        ),
        '8' => array(
            'id' => '8',
            'parent' => '2',
            'name' => 'Dallas',
        ),
        '9' => array(
            'id' => '9',
            'parent' => '3',
            'name' => 'Miami',
        ),
        '10' => array(
            'id' => '10',
            'parent' => '3',
            'name' => 'Orlando',
        ),
    );

    $states = array();
    foreach($cities as $id=>$city)
    {
        if (isset($cities[$city['parent']]['name']))
            $states[$cities[$city['parent']]['name']][] = $city;
    }


    ?>
    <select>
        <?php citiesSelect(0, $states, 0); ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add if else condition for optgroup, just change your function like this

```
<?php
function citiesSelect($ancestor, $array, $level, $selected = 0) {
    $has_children = false;
    $previousPid = '';

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['parent'] == $ancestor) {                   
            if ($has_children === false && $ancestor) {
                $has_children = true;
            }

        if(!$has_children){
            if($previousPid && $previousPid!=$value['id']){
                echo '</optgroup>';
            }
            echo '<optgroup label="'.$value['name'].'">';           
        }else{                  
 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" <?php echo ($value['id']) == $selected ? ' selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
 <?php
        }       
            citiesSelect($key, $array, $level, $selected);
        }
        $previousPid = $key;            
    }       
}
?>
```